# Datatables responsive en modal excede el tamaño del modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables, modal

He creado un formulario el cual es obtenido a traves de la funcion `Jquery.load();`

En un modal obtengo el formulario anterior en la clase

```
.modal-body-inteno
```

Pero no logro insertar dentro de un collapse un DataTable con responsive.

Cuando se carga el tamaño del ancho de la tabla excede el ancho de la tabla aunque aplique la API DATATABLES

La tabla se encuentra dentro de un collapse que es llamado y cargado en en la accion load a la class `.modal-body-inteno`
 PD: NO puedo hacer load desde stackoverflow al archivo php `/acciones/obtener.php`

```
 $("body").on('shown.bs.collapse','a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function(e){

  $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
     .columns.adjust()
     .responsive.recalc();  });
```

A esto quiero llegar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
  

$("body").on("click",".botonAgregar",function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

   
    
    urlToLoad = '/acciones/obtener.php?id='+id;
    //console.log(urlToLoad);
    $('#modalAgregar .modal-body-interno').load(urlToLoad,function(){
        
    
     
      var table = $('#tablaItemes').DataTable({responsive:true});

     
    $("body").on('shown.bs.collapse','a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function(e){

      $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
         .columns.adjust()
         .responsive.recalc();
});
});
  
   /* 
    $('body').on('show.bs.collapse',".panel", function (e) {
      $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust()
      .responsive.recalc();
    })
    */
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregar" data-id="25" class="botonAgregar btn btn-success ">
            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Agregar </a> 
            
            <p> <p>
            
            
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregar" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar</h4>
          </div>
          
      <div class="modal-body">



        <form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm2" action="acciones/procesa.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="" value="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button id="btnAdd2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon "></i> Agregar un ítem</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="employeeList2"></div>
          <div class="modal-body-interno"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-prymary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit2" class="btn btn-primary" >Guardar Información</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>                 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



<script type="text/html" id="addChild">
    <div class="tecnica">
    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
           
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
                   <input type="text" name="observacionRef-{0}" class="netEmp form-control" id="observacionRef-{0}" placeholder="Detalle Item" required>     
                </div>
                 <label for="observacionRef-{0}" generated="true" class="validation_error_message help-block control-label"></label>
             </div>
          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="idServicioProducto-{0}" class="control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                 <select class="netEmp form-control" id=" idServicioProducto-{0}" name="idServicioProducto-{0}" required>
                  <option value="">Seleccione Producto/Servicio ...</option>

                  <?php
                $tiposDocumentos = Helper::obtenerServicioProducto();
                foreach($tiposDocumentos as $row){
                     $selected = "";
                      if($value["idServicioProducto"] == $row['idServicioProducto'])
                      {
                        $selected = "selected";
                      }
                          $option  = '<option value="';
                          $option.= $row['idServicioProducto'].'"';
                          $option .= $selected.'>'.$row['nombreServicioProducto'].'</option>';
                          echo $option;
                        }
                      ?>

                   
                }
              ?>
            </select>
            </div>
              <label for="idServicioProducto-{0}" generated="true" class="validation_error_message help-block control-label"></label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cantidad-{0}" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                       <input type="number" name ="cantidad-{0}" class="netEmp cantidadsum form-control " id="cantidad-{0}" value="0" placeholder="Cantidad" required>     
                    </div>
                      <label for="cantidad-{0}" generated="true" class="validation_error_message help-block control-label"></label>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="monto-{0}" class="control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
                         <input type="number" name ="monto-{0}" class=" netEmp montosum form-control" id="monto-{0}" placeholder="Monto" value="0" required>      
                      </div>
                       <label for="monto-{0}" generated="true" class="validation_error_message help-block control-label"></label>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
           
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                      <select class="netEmp form-control" id="idTrabajador-{0}" name="idTrabajador-{0}" required >
                      <option value="">Encargado</option>
          <?php
          $tiposDocumentos = Helper::listarTrabajadores();
          foreach($tiposDocumentos as $row){
              echo '<option value="'.$row['idTrabajador'].'">'.$row['nombres'].' '.$row['apellidoPaterno'].'</option>';
          }
                    ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
          <label for="idTrabajador-{0}" generated="true" class="validation_error_message help-block control-label"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-right ">
               
                   <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove()" > Borrar </a>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div> 

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion era crear  primero la tabla y luego cambiar el .load por .ajax y definir a bajo nivel las opciones necesarias.

Todo esto debido al requerimiento de DataTable de que la tabla primero exista antes de aplicar API:Columns.Adjust()